# Grunt Imagemin not optimizing images

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

My images are not being optimized. Perhaps I am doing something wrong on my end but every other task is working for me except my imagemin task. I removed all other tasks and tried to run my task below but it doesn't execute.

There are also no messages in my terminal that indicate what the issue is. I am running this command with

`grunt imagemin`

but nothing happens.
The images are in `.jpg` format and are in my `img` folder. What i want to do is optimize/compress these images into my images folder in my `dist` folder.

I am also loading all registered nodes with `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);`

Would be nice if someone could help me out.

Here is my folder structure

```
Main Folder
| -- dist 
        |--- css
        |--- js
|-- img -- (images are here)
|-- js
|-- node_modules
|-- reports
|-- sass
|-- test 
|-- coverage
|-- _resources
|-- _bin
```

Here is my gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // A very basic default task.
  // grunt.registerTask('running', 'Log some stuff.', function() {
  //   grunt.log.write('Logging some stuff...').ok();
  // });

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); // using this to load all tasks

  grunt.initConfig({ 

      // Minify Images
      // Optimzes Images
      imagemin: {                            // Task
            dynamic: {
              files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'img/',
                src: ['*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                dest: 'dist/images/optimized/' 
              }]
            },
            options: {
              cache: false
          }
      } 
    });



  grunt.registerTask('imagemin', ['imagemin']);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can't have the name of `imagemin` as the name of the task. For example I originally had `grunt.registerTask('imagemin', ['imagemin']);`

All I did was rename my task to something like `minimizeImages`

`grunt.registerTask('minimizeImages', ['imagemin']);`

and this worked!